# Polymer Component to Affect External DOM

Tags: javascript, dom, polymer

I'm trying to write a polymer component which will affect the external dom.

```html
<dom-module id="ux-increase-font">
  <template>
    <style>
      :host {
        display: inline-block;
      }
    </style>
    <paper-button>
      <iron-icon icon="arrow-upward"></iron-icon>
      Increase
    </paper-button>
  </template>

  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'ux-increase-font',
      properties: {},
      listeners: {
        tap: 'increaseFont'
      },
      increaseFont: function() {
        fontSize = parseInt($('body').css('font-size'));
        if (fontSize > 10) {
          $('body').css('font-size', (fontSize + 2) + 'px');
        }
      }

    });
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

This is not working, and I'm not sure why. I've included domtastic on the host page, so $ should be available, and it is in console. But when I tap on the element, I get $ is not defined, ostensibly because domtastic is unavailable inside the widget's shadow DOM.

I'm trying to have my cake and eat it too, I want one copy of domtastic that I can call from inside the widget's shadow DOM to manipulate the parent page's real DOM.

Comment: I don't think that Shadow DOM is the problem. It doesn't affect JavaScript. Are you saying the in Shady DOM it works?

Comment: you're right doesn't work in the widget either :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tomasz was right, shadow DOM was not the problem. In my case, there was no font-size property set on body, so I wrote a check to apply a default value in case there's none already there:

```html
<script>
  Polymer({
    is: 'ux-increase-font',
    properties: {},
    listeners: {
      tap: 'increaseFont'
    },
    increaseFont: function() {
      fontSize = document.body.style.fontSize;
      if (!fontSize) {
        document.body.style.fontSize = '14px';
      } else {
        fontSize = parseInt(fontSize);
      }
      if (fontSize > 10) {
        document.body.style.fontSize = fontSize + 2 + 'px');
      }
    }
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Please explain what was the actual bug. It's not immediately obvious from just looking at your snippet